Extract regional data from USGS faults KMZ file
I am trying to extract fault data from USGS qfaults.kmz for a specific area so I can get it onto my Garmin GPS.  I got the USGS file on QGIS, can see the area I want on the map.  But I can't figure out how to export the data visible on the map to a new KMZ.

It would be helpful to know, what data type the KMZ contains.

Why not download the actual GIS data instead of the KMZ https://www.usgs.gov/programs/earthquake-hazards/faults

I'm trying to get fault map for my area to put into Garmin basecamp and then on to gps66.  The faults are recorded as thousands of vectors (linestring) placemarks.   Garmin rejects the usgs KMZ file. I tried the GIS files (GDB) and it says they are mis-formatted too.  Tried using mygeodata.cloud and it couldn't read the usgs files either. Tried to use QGIS. I have 8 layers so I merged into one ,selected my area and created attirbute table, but I can't export anything from that.  It's frustrating.  I can see everything I want on a map view in QGIS, but I can't figure out how to export it.

The GDB data has the faults as a single layer "Qfaults_2020".  Load that, Clip to your region of interest layer (or zoom to your region and clip/extract by extent) and then convert to KML.
